# Сложности со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Поляк ? вне всякого сомнения ?  был бы отправлен в нокаут, если бы (случаются же чудеса!) его соперник ? девяностакилограммовый страшно агрессивный чернокожий ? по собственной оплошности не получил тяжёлую травму ноги, прямым следствием (чего или которой ?) были (была?) остановка боя и объявление  его итога ? технического поражения мистера "не повезло".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поляк, вне всякого сомнения, [оборот, эквивалентный вводному слову " несомненно"] был бы отправлен в нокаут, если бы (случаются же чудеса!) его соперник, [обособленное приложение] девяностакилограммовый страшно агрессивный чернокожий, по собственной оплошности не получил тяжёлую травму ноги, [определительное придаточHое] следствием которой стали  остановка боя и объявление его итогa [ приложение ] - технического поражения мистера "Не повезло".

Желательно заменить "были" на "стали":  чётче смысл причинно-следственной связи, что совсем не лишнее в довольно длинном и не самом простом для восприятия предложении;  "имя" мистера всё-таки привычнее видеть начинающимся с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Прошу прощения за "дополнение" - там подлежащее, конечно

Comment: Не кажется ли Вам, что "девяностакилограммовый страшно агрессивный чернокожий" - это не уточняющий оборот, а обычное обособленное приложение, так же как и слова "технического поражения мистера "Не повезло"? -это не дополнение и не подлежащее, а опять приложение , которое носит пояснительный характер, поэтому выделяется с помощью тире?

Comment: mueller , поскольку там действительно обособленное приложение, тогда вам лучше исправить основной ответ, чтобы ответ был полностью правильным.

Comment: Верно. Исправил.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, mueller !

Comment: А зачем сочинять такие многоэтажные неудобочитаемые конструкции?

Comment: Слово "грамотеи" пишется именно так. Это от слова "грамота", а не от слова "грамматика". Можно пользоваться орфографическим словарем.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаемый вариант

Поляк, вне всякого сомнения,  был бы отправлен в нокаут, если бы (случаются же чудеса!) его соперник, девяностокилограммовый, страшно агрессивный чернокожий, по собственной оплошности не получил тяжёлую травму ноги, прямым следствием  чего стала остановка боя и объявление его итога  - технического поражения мистера "не повезло".

Comment: С п а с и б о, Vera !